# Compare Values in a List and create Boolean Python

Tags: python

I have a program in which I'm supposed to create a list of 5 numbers and then compare these items to see if they are all the same.  I am supposed to compare the numbers of the list and then return a Boolean if it is true or not.  (I'm relatively new to programming and am only allowed to use the random Library and the regular library).  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

I've tried things such as

```
if aList[0] = aList[1] and aList [2] and... aList[4]: 
   Return = True.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `set()`:

```
def all_the_same(lst):
    # all values in aList are the same.
    return len(set(lst)) == 1
```

This works for any list of hashable values; strings, integers, booleans, tuples with hashable contents, floats (if they are exactly the same), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
return all(aList[0] == aList[i] for i in range(1, len(aList))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a python3 variation that has short circuit behavior:

```
ix = iter(aList)
iy = iter(aList)
next(iy)
if all(x == y for x, y in zip(ix, iy)):
    do something
```

Comment: Not allowed to use outside libraries other than random

Comment: Note, in python 2, `zip` is eager (returns a list) instead of lazy; you can get the iterator version of zip as `itertools.izip` in the python standard library.